# Auto bumping sorted number fields up upon insertion of new line

Tags: excel

We have an excel sheet with multiple columns with about 5 or 6 that are sorted by number.

Is it possible to have it so that when we insert a new project and assign it a pre existing number to have the current project with that number automatically bump up to the next highest and so forth for the remaining numbers?

[image]

Example:

```
          Rank
Project 1  1   3
Project 2  2   1
Project 3  3   2
```

Insert new project   assign 3 and  2   have project 3 bump to rank 4 and 3?

Comment: Anything is possible. With what little you've described for your business logic, there are a number of ways to implement this. To start you need to define (from your users) just how they will be inserting a new project (e.g. a userform, right-click->insert, button click) and that will guide how you implement this. We'll help you get your code working if you show us what you've done and the specific problem/questions you have.

Comment: I have added an image of the exact file, I believe we will want to be able to just insert a line, fill out the project name and ranks, but have the other project ranks bump up based on what we give the new one.

Comment: It's still possible, but SO is not a code-writing service. Try to implement this yourself and when you run into problems we're happy to help you overcome them and improve your code to achieve a solution.